# How to measure react native (Expo) app startup time?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo hybrid app (Managed workflow), running on Expo SDK v37 (React Native v0.61).

I'm struggling to find the best way to measure the time it takes from the moment when the user starts the app until the splash screen disappears.

How would you approach this?

PS: I would use Firebase Performance Monitoring instead, [if it was available for Expo Managed apps](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/firebase-performance-monitoring). But it isn't yet.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I see two approaches:

1. For pure react-native projects you can use [react-native-startup-time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-startup-time) library.
   However I'm not sure, whether you can just add this library and start to use it, since it's required linking.
   But in any case you can `eject` your project and add this library.
2. If you don't want to `eject` expo project I can suggest you to update your project to SDK 38. It has support for RN 0.62.2 and flipper integration as well. So you can setup [flipper-plugin-react-native-performance](https://github.com/oblador/flipper-plugin-react-native-performance) and check the performance.

I hope I helped a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, the app is using the Expo Managed workflow, and I'm not planning to `eject` anytime soon. Especially for this :)